# Date of first session segment using Analytics V4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Does anyone know how to build a dynamic segment, using Google Core Reporting API V4, that gets only users that had a given event action, and for which the **first session** was recorded on DD/MM/YYY.

Ex: looking for all users who "installed" (first session) the (mobile) app on Dec 14, and have generate at least one event "clicked xxxx".

No way to find this in docs.

On google analytics dashboard, this can be achieved by creating a segment with a "**Date of first session**" value.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this with a segment but i'll give you another option:

You can take advantage of the ['ga:sessionCount'](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_sessioncount) parameter. Just make a query for all sessions en **X** day and another one of all **N** events in **Y** day. Finally, cross the data of **X** and **Y** day and you will end up with every user that had his first session on **X** day and made **N** events on **Y** day.

(Use ClientID as **KEY** when crossing the data)

Comment: Hmm, could be interesting. I thought we had no way to get the list of unique user (client, in fact) ids as part of the results. Is there a way to check how this ClientID behaves directly from the google analytics dashboard first? Couldn't find it on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets either btw.

Comment: @BenjaminPiette Im sorry, GA actually uses a clientID but it doesnt allow you to access it so our guru did this: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/ and i got really used to having always those dimentions configured. Hope it helps